# Classes in directory .IdeaIC14\system\jars\ outdated

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have added a contructor in a class.
Using this constructor within the same module.
Signature

Compiling the code with no errors
In the module compile path i found the right .class file.
In the directory C:\Useres\me.IdeaIC14\system\jars\ is a jar file with my module name, including a wrong(outdated) .class file. In the class file the added constructor is missing.

When I debug it loads the class from the outdated jar file reuslting to the runtime error method (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V not found

I am using IntelliJ IDEA CU 14
Invalidate chaches has no effect.
Close the IDE and delete the content of C:\Useres\me.IdeaIC14\system\jars\ doesnt help

Comment: Did you try invalidate caches, close intellij?

Comment: Used command File>Invalidate Caches/Restart>Invalidate and Restart

Comment: How are your dependencies set up, and how is the jar file generated? Normally when one module of your project depends on another one, you add a module dependency, and there is no jar file involved.

Comment: -I use Module depencies and a dependency directory ($Project\bin) with jars located

-The jars are build with ant

Comment: The affected modules are build with IDEA make.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a circular dependecy.
After changing the dependecies it works fine